system on a computer, should Windows or CentOS Stream be installed first?
When installing a dual-system on a computer (one is the Windows system and the other is the CentOS Stream system), I am in a dilemma. On the one hand, I know that the Windows system is excellent in the compatibility of daily office software and game support, while CentOS Stream has unique advantages in server-related applications and some professional development fields. I am not sure whether the installation order will have an impact on the stability of the dual-system, the boot program, and subsequent use. For example, will installing Windows first cause boot loading problems when installing CentOS Stream? Or after installing CentOS Stream first, will some functions of the Windows system be limited, such as the installation and recognition of hardware drivers? Or is the installation order related to the computer's hardware configuration (such as whether the hard disk type is a mechanical hard disk or a solid-state drive, memory size, etc.)? So, should I install Windows or CentOS Stream first? I hope experienced friends can give me some guidance and suggestions.

You can only have a dual system in San Marino, Andorra or Eswatini. Also, this is the Politics Stack Exchange.

"I am not sure whether the installation order ..." - Microsoft OSes tend to be unaware and/or inconsiderate of other OS installations, so always install that first. Linux will allow and can perform a dual-boot installation.

I am assuming you mean a "dual-boot" system meaning that the OS'es are totally isolated from each other: either they are installed to separate partitions or separate disks. Meaning that you are not planning to use a VM or WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux).
Given that the OS have been correctly installed to isolated disks environments (separate partitions or disks) I am only aware of two potential interactions:
#1 - You will have to split up your disk(s) - so if you have a total of 2TB you might choose to allocate 1 TB to each OS, hence neither system will be able to use the entire (2TB) of the total disk space. **
** - There are some options to re-use disk between the OS'es, but I am going to assume you want total safely, hence will maintain total isolation.
#2 - Windows likes to reboot the system after installing patches - you probably want to make Windows the default OS, so that if the system reboots by itself, it goes back into windows.

TL;DR - With correctly isolated installations, it makes no difference which order you install Windows and Linux.
